# How to search a value from an array inside another arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a Telegram bot that users can save questionnaires in it, the bot's script will save the user information as a `JSON` like this:

```
{ 
   "userID":{ 
      "questionnaireTitle":{ 
         "Question One":{ 
            "Answer1":0,
            "Answer2":0,
            "Answer3":0
         },
         "Question Two":{ 
            "Answer1":0,
            "Answer2":0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Well, after a questionnaire got saved, bot makes buttons of answers then user can share it and when someone clicks on an answer's button, a query returns. In this query, I can just get the button value, my question is how can I search the clicked button value (the answer that users have selected!) from these arrays?
I done this by using `foreach loop` at this way:

```
$json = '{"userID":{"questionnaireTitle":{"Question One":{"Answer1":0,"Answer2":0,"Answer3":0},"Question Two":{"Answer1":0,"Answer2":0}}}}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data['userID'] as $questionnares => $questions){
    foreach($questions as $question => $answers){
        foreach($answers as $answer => $number){
            if($queryValue == $answer){ //e.g. $queryValue is the name of selected inline button of bot.
                //code to be executed, increasing $number of $answer for example!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it takes too much time to done what I expect!

---

When I was writing this question, I thought about putting the `questionnaireTitle`, `question` and everything I may need to do instead of doing this loop, in the bot inline button value, but I'll be thankful if you let me know how to do searching a string value like `$queryValue` from an array like `$data` and get its parent values?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: you can try to search JSON using regular expressions for text like '{$queryValue:<numeric value>}', then grab numeric value out, increment it and replace with {$queryValue:<new numeric value>}, but be careful and accurate with multiple results

Comment: @AksenP I want to know how to search arrays like `$data` in this example for a value like `Answer3` and find what's its parent! (for example `Question One` is my desired output here!).

Comment: @AnatoliyR It seems working for increasing the answer value, but I want to know how to search these arrays!

Comment: @MohammadHoodaji my idea is to search upon JSON representation, not an array. If you want to keep array structure and search inside, you can research [here](https://www.php.net/RecursiveIteratorIterator), that class may help you

Comment: [Answers should be different](https://3v4l.org/ev1Ff)

Comment: @AnatoliyR That class looks useful, thanks.

Comment: @AksenP yes, answers actually are different, but you used `foreach loop` as I used too! I was looking for a better and more quick way.

Comment: @MohammadHoodaji, as you can see I've removed 1 foreach. Also, you won't find a 'quicker' way. Btw, this function returns result at the first appearance of the answer. But I'm sure you can't figure out what's going on here)

Comment: @AksenP yes you removed one of foreach loops by searching inside of `$data['userID']["questionnaireTitle"]`, I want to search inside of $data! In my real code I even should use another foreach loop just for getting `userID` if I use these loops!